# R - OSX Mountain Lion and CPU Limit

Tags: r, osx-mountain-lion

I am collecting data via SQL query though R. I have a loop to pull small chunks of a large table, save the chunk and drop the chunk, on repeat for an hour or so till the whole table is in flat files in my RSQL directory.

However, R shoots a Cputime limit exceeded: 24 error every so often.

I am running Mountain Lion.

I have tried

> nice -19n R CMD BATCH myscript.R

and the OS continues to kill the process at odd intervals. I do not believe the script to be getting stuck on a particular operation, it just takes a while to plough through the loop.

The loop looks like so..

```
for (i in 1:64){
  foobyte <- NULL
  for (j in 0:7){
    max id = 1000000
    rows = 1e5
    to = max_id * (rows * j) - (i * 7 * rows)
    from = max_id * (rows * (j-1)) - (1 * 7 * rows)
    foobit <- queryDB(paste("SELECT * FROM foobar where id <= ', to,' and id > ',from,';")
    foobyte <- rbind(foobit, foobyte)
    }
  filename <- paste("/my/data/dir/foobyte", j, ".csv", sep="")
  write.table(foobyte, filename)
}
```

It runs for 30-90 minutes before crashing. I will try firing up R from a shell script calling ulimit in only that terminal session, and see how this works.

Comment: Can you post the loop you're running? I've left scripts running overnight in the interactive terminal on OSX Mountain Lion without running into that issue.

Comment: Try running it within the OS X GUI REPL, just out of curiosity?

Comment: I have. I see the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Tried ulimit... Appears I do not have access, even via sudo. I get the same output from

```
ulimit -a -H
```

before and after giving

```
ulimit -t 12000 # sets cputime limit to 12000 seconds from 600 seconds
```

SOLVED via Debian Virtual Machine. If someone has a Mountain Lionic solution, please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

A cursory google search for "Cputime limit exceeded: 24" shows me that this is not an R specific error.

Based on the loop you've posted, I'm guessing its exceeding the cpu time limit on the `queryDB` call, due to the size of the chunks you're retrieving from the database.

I'm not sure if your `from` and `to` math checks out: At rows = 1e5, you're loading 1e11 ids, if you reduce it so rows = 1, you're loading 1e6 ids from the table.

Either way, try reducing size of the chunks you're loading from the database, and see if that helps

Comment: Switched my i's and j's around. The queries take 3-5 seconds, and the loop runs well several times through. I do not believe that the queries are producing the cputime limit exceeded error.

Comment: Odd. From your loop there are three areas which take a non-negligible amount of time: 1) Retrieving a big chunk from the database, 2) writing a big table out to file, and 3) rbind.

Comment: Also odd that it runs well on a Debian VM with a fractions of the host's resources.